# python unittest handle exception handling

Tags: python

I want to unittest an exception handling in my unittest and I'm using `assertRaises` to check if exception is thrown.

```
class Add():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if type(x) != int or type(y) != int:
            raise Exception('Not a valid number')


Add(None, None)            

import unittest
from test2 import Add
class TestAdd(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_check_for_valid_nos(self):
        self.assertRaises(Exception, Add(None,None))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this piece of code it still raises exception. I expect the test to pass saying that the exception has been raised.

Comment: Did you try by removing your `Add(None, None)` line?

Comment: You can't call Add in the argument list, this will execute Add before calling assertRaises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not directly execute your `Add` function when passing it to `assertRaises`, rather pass the positional arguments afterwards.

```
assertRaises(Exception, Add, None, None)
```

This allows the internal implementation of `assertRaises` to control executing your function and checking for the right exception. If you invoke the function directly, such as `assertRaises(Exception, Add(None, None))`, then `assertRaises` must fully evaluate `Add(None, None)` *before* its own function body can execute, because it has to consume the result of that function call as an argument for its input. This is an unprotected call to `Add` with arguments that will trigger an exception, so the `Exception` is raised before the actual function body of `assertRaises` is ever used.

Comment: still same issue...I tried this - self.assertRaises(Exception, Add,None,None)

Comment: Are you calling `Add(None, None)` somewhere in either of the two files? You have it in your source code just above the `import` statement. Where is that? Maybe it is throwing the exception when it tries to import the `test2` module because `Add(None, None)` is in that file?

Comment: Thats right..I had a instance in the source code..thanks

Comment: Note that you still would have needed the original change too .. rather than calling `Add(None, None)` as an argument to `assertRaises`. Either one of these invocations of `Add(None, None)` would cause it to fail.

Comment: Wow, assertRaises accepts arguments... I thought I would need a `lambda` to wrap my code.